# How can I use webpack in .net core 2.0 by nuget?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have learned asp.net yet.What's more I am also a beginner of .net core and webpack.Now I am tring to use webpack in .net core.
I downloaded the webpack by nuget like this:
[image]

But I don't konw how to continue to configure it.I tried to follow the tutorial as https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/
However,the tutorial is using nodejs.
I searched about "Setting up Webpack in ASP.NET Core" in google.Whereas,all of them are build by NPM,but not nuget.
I wonder if there is a way to build it by nuget?Would you like to teach me or give me a tutorial about this?Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look at the project documentation reachable via the nuget packages _project site_? It offers some getting started help.

https://github.com/xabikos/aspnet-webpack

Comment: Thank you and let me try if it works~.

Comment: @ChrisJansson I downloaded the demo and run it.But after few seconds the IIS crashed,oh my god.I tried to read all the code of the project every line.Maybe I am a beginner,I am afraid I can only know little of them.

Comment: It might just be the case that the project isn't all that relevant anymore. I had a look at the ASP.NET Core docs and support WebpackMddleware officially now. 

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services#webpack-dev-middleware

The SPA templates should give you a fuller idea of how they envision you set it up as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/

On the otherhand, it's common to handle front end build sources outside of the ASP.NET pipeline with nodejs tools just like the webpack tutorial showed.